# How do I create a unix timestamp that doesn't adjust for localtime?

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

So I have datetime objects in UTC time and I want to convert them to UTC timestamps.  The problem is, time.mktime makes adjustments for localtime.

So here is some code:

```
import os
import pytz
import time
import datetime

epoch = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1))
print time.mktime(epoch.timetuple())

os.environ['TZ'] = 'UTC+0'
time.tzset()
print time.mktime(epoch.timetuple())
```

Here is some output:

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec 25 2009, 08:52:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import pytz
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> 
>>> epoch = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1))
>>> print time.mktime(epoch.timetuple())
25200.0
>>> 
>>> os.environ['TZ'] = 'UTC+0'
>>> time.tzset()
>>> print time.mktime(epoch.timetuple())
0.0
```

So obviously if the system is in UTC time no problem, but when it's not, it is a problem.  Setting the environment variable and calling time.tzset works but is that safe?  I don't want to adjust it for the whole system.

Is there another way to do this?  Or is it safe to call time.tzset this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `calendar` module contains [`calendar.timegm`](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) which solves this problem.

`calendar.timegm`(tuple)

> An unrelated but handy function that takes a time tuple such as returned by the `gmtime()` function in the [`time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#module-time) module, and returns the corresponding Unix timestamp value, assuming an epoch of 1970, and the POSIX encoding. In fact, [`time.gmtime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.gmtime) and [`timegm()`](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) are each others’ inverse.